# Calculate average of array in Scala - Result truncated

Tags: scala, stream, average

I've been learning Scala for a few days with TDD, so I have the following Unit Test:

```
test("CalcStats.calculateAverage should return average") {
    assert(CalcStats.calculateAverage(Array(6, 9, 15, -2, 92, 11)) === 21.833333)
  }
```

As far as I think, the following should make it pass:

```
def calculateAverage(values: Array[Int]): Float = {
    values.sum / values.size
  }
```

However, I am getting **21.0** instead of **21.833333**, so the Unit Test will fail ❌

```
Expected :21.833333
Actual   :21.0
```

As long as I am specifying that the result will be a Float, I thought that was enough, but it is definitely not. What should I do to avoid the truncation in the result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember floating point arithmetic is not exact in computers. So, two advices. 1 Use **Double** instead of **Float**. 2. Compare with an error, **Scalatest** provides as syntax like `foo shouldBe x +/-0.01` or if you do not like fancy syntax you can just `math.abs(expected - result) < 0.01` - Finally, I would recommend you to do not use plain **Arrays**, but rather concrete real collections like **List**, **Vector** or **ArraySeq**.

Comment: Indeed, it does work better with Double, thank you! Why not using a plain array, if it is enough? (The simpler tends to be the better)

Comment: Because plain **Arrays** are: mutable, invariant and not really collections so you can not use them in methods that accept things like **Seq** or **IterableOnce**. Arrays are a primitive of the JVM which is useful for interoperation with platform native code _(e.g. Java or JS)_ or performance-sensitive code. In all other cases is better to use a normal immutable collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
def calculateAverage(values: Array[Int]): Float = {
values.sum / values.size}
```

underlying result `values.sum / values.size` has type `Int` (21)
So, the compiler extend it to `Float`.
Try the following:

```
def calculateAverage(values: Array[Int]): Float = {
values.sum.toFloat / values.size  }
```

Comment: A very good catch Oleg! Just for the record, and following @Luis Miguel Mejia Suarez suggestion, I've realized it works better with Double. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This method should work - just a simple recursive method to add all the values from the list and, when empty, divide with the total size of the list.

```
def getAverage(list: List[Double]): Double = {
  def loop(list: List[Double], acc: Double = 0): Double = {
    list match {
      case Nil => acc / list.size
      case element :: tail => loop(tail, acc + element)
    }  
  }

  loop(list)
}
```